# Custom Tabwiget for Android

Tags: android, tabs

I have designed an activity which I'm using for tab(Custom Global activity),this activity has different buttons like tab and clicking on buttons calling corresponding activity so if I'm calling A(suppose) activity and as then call B(suppose)activity and coming back on A,in this case A activity is created again.I want this activity should behave like `tabwidget` and start from `onResume()`.Is this possible or not if yes then how please suggest me.`Thanks`

**Global TabLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1a1a1a"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/liveTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_livetv_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_movie_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vod"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_vod_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/events"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_event_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_playlist_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code for Global tab**

```
public class Header extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageView liveTV;
    private ImageView movies;
    private ImageView vod;
    private ImageView events;
    private ImageView playlist;
    public static String tab = null;
    public static boolean destroy = false;

    public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;

        String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;

        li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(infService);
        li.inflate(R.layout.header, this, true);
        liveTV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.liveTV);
        movies = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movies);
        vod = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vod);
        events = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.events);
        playlist = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playlist);
        liveTV.setOnClickListener(this);
        movies.setOnClickListener(this);
        vod.setOnClickListener(this);
        events.setOnClickListener(this);
        playlist.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void init() {
        // setting selector for selected tab
        if (tab.equals("movies")) {
            destroy = true;
            movies.setSelected(true);
            liveTV.setSelected(false);
            vod.setSelected(false);
            events.setSelected(false);
            playlist.setSelected(false);
        } else if (tab.equals("vod")) {
            destroy = true;
            vod.setSelected(true);
            liveTV.setSelected(false);
            movies.setSelected(false);
            events.setSelected(false);
            playlist.setSelected(false);
        } else if (tab.equals("events")) {
            destroy = true;
            events.setSelected(true);
            liveTV.setSelected(false);
            movies.setSelected(false);
            vod.setSelected(false);
            playlist.setSelected(false);
        } else if (tab.equals("playlist")) {
            destroy = true;
            playlist.setSelected(true);
            liveTV.setSelected(false);
            movies.setSelected(false);
            vod.setSelected(false);
            events.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            destroy = true;
            liveTV.setSelected(true);
            movies.setSelected(false);
            vod.setSelected(false);
            events.setSelected(false);
            playlist.setSelected(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        //have to put here code for click
        }
    }

}
```

then have to put only following code in xml like another view

```
<com.media.ui.Header
            android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: Are you creating custom tab??

Comment: have you created the TabGroupACtivty class which Extends ActivityGroup??

Comment: have look my have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Please write below code instead of your code for add multiple activities in one TabActivity, it will solve your problem.

ActivityStack.java

```
private Stack<String> stack;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (stack == null)
        stack = new Stack<String>();
    // start default activity
    push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, Tab_SampleActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    pop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    pop();
}

public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        stack.push(id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

public void pop() {
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        finish();
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
    if (stack.size() > 0) {
        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

TabActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice));
        spec1.setContent(intent1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Tab Sample Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), SecondActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("SecondActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), ThirdActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("ThirdActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Add Below XML files into your res/layout folder.

1) tab_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

2) main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tabsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityStack"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And see below link for more information on add multiple activities under one TabActivity with complete example.

[Android - Multiple Android Activities under one TabActivity](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Dipak But Actually don't have to use tabwidget because our requirement is different

Comment: @Dipu Then tell me what is your requirement?

Comment: @Dipu I don't understand your question properly so i will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce the using of tabs in your application, then the best way, IMO, is to use [`FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) from support library as the standard [`TabActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) has become deprecated.

There is also an example which shows how to use this component and it's located inside `<your_sdk_folder_location>/extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos`.

This standard component allows you to customize your tabs as you wish instead of inventing the bicycle.